# Разместить элемент над всплывающей клавиатурой iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

На сайте есть фиксированное всплывающее окно, имеющее 100% высоты экрана.
Сверху и снизу прикреплены элементы высотой по 50 пикселей, а всю внутреннюю часть занимает `textarea`. Мне нужно, чтобы при фокусе `textarea` нижний блок был всегда над всплывающей клавиатурой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На iPhone при появлении клавиатуры, размер окна не уменьшается и Footer, Header прячутся за краями.
Пробовал получать размер окна с помощью JavaScript, но результат отдается без учета клавиатуры.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833049/how-to-make-fixed-content-go-above-ios-keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно сложная задача. Необходимо самостоятельно обсчитывать изменения перед фокусировкой и после. Для примера - при открытии клавиатуры меняется window.pageYOffset

Answer (score 0):

На картинках ваша работа уже, или пример того, что должно быть?
Извините, не могу пока что еще это в комментарии к вопросу написать.

Попробуйте position: fixed; использовать для футера.

Comment: Да, простите, не понятно. На правой картинке - так как хотелось бы. Position: fixed не помогает, IOS не считает, что видимая зона уменьшается и всё остаётся так же, как если бы клавиатуры не было.